# Set origin in modifier-stack

Tags: modeling, modifiers

im modeling a sort of complex tube right now. For this I model just a single patch and use array modifiers to get it to the right dimensions. After that I use a 'SimpleDeform -Bend' modifier to make it a tube.
Now I want to use a curve-deform modifier on this, but since the object center (origin) is not in the middle of the tube I get unpredictable results.

As a workaround I can apply the array- and simpledeform modifiers and set the origin manually before the curve-deform, but since I'm in early production I would rather keep that stuff as I have not decided yet on the dimensions and thus still like to have the modifiers available.

Any ideas? thx

edit: [simple examplescene](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/36249)
and a screenshot....see how the curve is nicely in the center when the modifier stack is frozen
[image]

Comment: This is not possible yet, I don't think; there was a plan to add a patch to do this, but it seems to have faced away.

Comment: can we see the model , in most cases moving the model or the curve will do

Comment: modified the original post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have some options to try :

1- just move the curve and try to approximate the result you want

[image]

( moved the curve a little bit down )

2- use another modifiers stack to create the same shape
[image]

now you get the origin in the center of the circle

[image]

the modifiers used are :

[image]